# how to change the pixel value to zero when it corresponds to a slope above 15%

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, raster-conversion

i have a landuse raster data and raster data containing slopes in percentage. i want to assign pixel value as zero which corresponds to slope more than 15%. i tried using 'extract by mask' but i'm unable to get the desired result. is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to do this using **Map Algebra** is described under the topic of **[Conditional evaluation with Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000008000000)** in the **ArcGIS for Desktop Online Help**.

Comment: +1 Another way uses the fact that true results evaluate to 1 and false to 0, whence an expression like `("slope" <= 15) * "landuse"` ought to accomplish the same as `Con`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the *Raster Calculator* in **Whitebox GAT** (http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/) you would enter the following line:

```
[output raster]=IF(([slope]>15),0,[landuse])
```

I'm sure that ArcGIS has an equivalent statement in its calculator as well.